# Chart.js: Multiple stacked datasets

Tags: charts, chart.js

I am trying to create bar chart with each bar have different sets of data.

This is how normally things work in chart.js (without nested array of data) but this is not helpful for me:

```
datasets: [
  {
    label: "My First Label",
    stack: "Stack 0" 
    data: [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  },
  {
    label: "My Second Label",
    stack: "Stack 0" 
    data: [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  }
]
```

And the below code doesn't work as I am trying to feed data with nested array, is there a way to make it work?

```
datasets: [
  {
    label: "My First Label",
    data: [[65, 59, 20, 81], [56, 55, 40]],
  },
  {
    label: "My Second Label",
    data: [[65, 59, 20], [30, 81, 56, 55, 40]],
  }
]
```